# Python - Panda - Get last non empty value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Consider I have one DataFrame like this:

```
ID,    name,  result_1,   result_2
1 ,    John,       8.9,        1.1
2 ,    John,       3.3,          
3 ,    John,          ,        9.9
4 ,    Mark,       8.8,        4.5
5 ,    Mark,       5.5,
```

What I need to retrieve is the 'result_1' and 'result_2' values of the greatest ID, considering non-empty 'results'. 
My final DataFrame must be a 2 line table like this:

```
name,  result_1,   result_2
John,       3.3,        9.9
Mark,       5.5,        4.5
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think your question is actually more elaborate than you make it seem. Could you define exactly what you're trying to do? In your example, you have selected and combined results from four different rows, and I can't infer the logic that you used from the way you stated the question.

Comment: Can you show what you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
ID    name,  result_1   result_2
1    John,       8.9         1.1
2     John,       3.3        N/A
3     John,       N/A        9.9
4     Mark,       8.8        4.5
5     Mark,       5.5        N/A


df = df.groupby(['name,']).last()
df[['result_1', 'result_2' ]]



#          result_1  result_2
 #   name,                    
 #   John,       3.3       9.9
 #   Mark,       5.5       4.5
```